# SQLAlchemy Regex with MySQL database using \b

Tags: python, mysql, regex, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to do a regex search with SQLAlchemy like so:

```
db.session.query(Users).filter(User.name.op('regexp')(r'\bJohn\b')).all()
```

However although I have users in my MySQL database with the name 'John', I get no results returned.

If I remove `\b` from either side of `John` in the regex query then I get the result with users such as `John Smith` or just `John`. However the issue with having no `\b` on either side would mean people with `Johnson` in their name would also appear.

Why does using `\b` not return results? Thanks.

Comment: try `^John$` instead of word boundaries

Comment: @PruthviRaj But if a user has a word before or after 'John' it would not return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the way MySQL uses regex. Instead of using `\b` for word boundaries, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` should be used like so:

```
db.session.query(Users).filter(User.name.op('regexp')(r'[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]')).all()
```